# Cannot proceed with multiform view in class based views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I need to create a class based view that:

1. will display one form
2. based on the input from the first form will create another one: the first input is a JSON file that contains the name of the files that need to be passed to the next.

I'm stuck - I cannot get the view to act on saving the first form (called initial in the code). I minimized the initial_form_valid function to just one print and it still doesn't run (before it was an attempt to check if the form is valid or not and print the result to the console).

And yes, unfortunately for now I must keep putting the CBV in a function to preserve the original urls.py structure.

views.py

```
def firmware_cbv(request):

    class Firmware_view(MultiFormsView, TemplateView):
        template_name = 'path/firmware_cbv.html'
        form_classes = {'initial': forms.InitialFirmwareForm,
                        'details': forms.DetailsFirmwareForm}

        def get_success_url(self):
            return self.request.path

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(Firmware_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            forms = self.get_forms(self.form_classes)
            context["initialSent"] = False
            context['forms'] = forms
            context.update({"key1": "val1",
                            "key2": "val2"})
            print("the context is now", context)
            return context

        def initial_form_valid(self):
            print("the self in initial form valid is", self)

        def details_form_valid(self, form):
            new_firmware = form.save(self.request)
            return form.details(self.request, new_firmware, self.get_success_url())

    fw_view = Firmware_view.as_view()(request)

    return fw_view
```

forms.py

```
class InitialFirmwareForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()

    def clean_file(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data.get('file')
        if file is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("File field is required.")
        return file

    def save(self, request):
        print("save method was ran")
        return None
```

firmware_cbv.html

```
<div id="main-form">
    <form method="post" action="this/view/path" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ forms.initial.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="initial" value="Add version" class="btn btn-block"
                    style="width:40%; margin-top:30px;">
    </form>
</div>
```

I use this approach to MultiFormsView, but I had to change it slightly, because I don't use model forms but just forms:

https://gist.github.com/jamesbrobb/748c47f46b9bd224b07f