# Multiple form view, in which JSON fed to one form, constitutes another in Class Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I want to create a class based view in Django that after receiving one form, will translate it to another and then accept the second form (both forms accept files - the first just one, the other several).

I have tried the approach with MultiFormsView (you can check the question here):
[Cannot proceed with multiform view in class based views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76357340/cannot-proceed-with-multiform-view-in-class-based-views)

And then I moved a bit further with Tarquiniuses help with another method:

[I cannot pass the values between the methods in classBasedView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76406440/i-cannot-pass-the-values-between-the-methods-in-classbasedview)

Now the code looks like this:

Django:

```
@user_authenticated
def firmware_cbv2(request):
    class Firmware_view(FormView):
        template_name = "dev_tools/firmware_cbv2.html"
        form_class = forms.InitialFirmwareForm2

        def get_success_url(self):
            return self.request.path

        def form_invalid(self, form):
            print("the form is invalid")
            return super().form_invalid(form)

        def get_context_data(self, message=None, bundle=None,**kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['bundle'] = bundle
            context['message'] = message
            return context

        def form_valid(self, form):
            bundle, message = {}, {}
            if request.FILES:
                if len(request.FILES) < 2 and "file" in request.FILES:
                    file = request.FILES["file"]
                    try:
                        content = json.loads(file.read().decode('utf-8'))
                        folder_name = utils.format_folder_name(content["title"])
                        units = []
                        for unit in content["units"]:
                            units.append(unit)
                        bundle["units"] = units
                        bundle["file"] = {
                            "name": folder_name,
                            "content": json.dumps(content)
                        }
                        message.update({
                            "type": "info",
                            "content": "The form was parsed successfully"
                        })
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("there was an error", e)
                else:
                    print("I am in else")
            else:
                print("not a good name in the form")
            return render(self.request, self.template_name, context=self.get_context_data(message=message, bundle=bundle))

    fc2_view = Firmware_view.as_view()(request)

    return fc2_view
```

In this view, the new form appears (defined in JavaScript with jQuery), but I cannot capture the values from it:

```
const bundle = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('bundle').textContent);
    if (bundle != null) {
        create_the_secondary_form();
    };

    function create_the_secondary_form() {
        const units = bundle.units

        const formDiv = $('#details-form');

        if (units) {
            //dissappearing the main form
            $('#main-form').addClass('dismissed');

            //creating the new form based on JSON contents
            const newForm = $(`
                <form action="{% url 'dev_tools.firmware_cbv' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
                `);
            //creating an input with a label for each expected file
            var nameDict = {}
            for (var unitNo = 0; unitNo < units.length; unitNo++) {
                const fileBrand = "file-" + (unitNo+1);
                const fileId = fileBrand + "-id"

                nameDict[fileBrand] = (units[unitNo]["file"])
                const unitLabel = $(`<label for="`+fileId+`-btn" style="margin-right:5px">`+units[unitNo]["title"]+`:</label>`);
                const frontInput = $(`
                                    <input id="`+fileId+`-btn" type="button" value="{% label 'add' %}"
                                    onclick="document.getElementById('`+fileId+`').click();" style="margin-bottom:15px"
                                    class="solo-capitalized">
                `);
                const unitInput = $(`<input id="`+fileId+`" type="file" name="`+fileBrand+`" required class="dismissed">`);

                const br = document.createElement('br');

                newForm.append(unitLabel);
                newForm.append(frontInput);
                newForm.append(unitInput);
                newForm.append(br);
            }
            //pack the full dictionary of file-tags paired with their names
            const ndString = JSON.stringify(nameDict);
            newForm.append("<input id='of-name' type='text' name='of-name' value='"+ bundle.file.name +"' hidden>");
            newForm.append("<input id='of-content' type='text' name='of-content' value='"+ bundle.file.content +"' hidden>");
            newForm.append("<input id='file-names' type='text' name='file-names' value='"+ ndString +"' hidden>");
            newForm.append(`
                <input type="submit" value="add files" class="btn solo-btn-blue solo-text-bold btn-block"
                style="width:40%; margin-top:30px;">
                `);
            $(formDiv).append(newForm);
            $(formDiv).removeClass("dismissed");
        }
    }
```

I think defining the post method might help here, but on the other hand Tarquinius helped me out by removing this very method from the previous iteration, so it also might destroy current functionality.